# Does google know that 2 websites are using the same template/wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was wondering if google know that 2 websites use the same template (wordpress theme in my case) and how.

Does it index html structure and compares with other sites, css classes, attributes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google can see what theme you are using by crawling your styles.css file included with the theme.

Google doesn't penalize you for using the same theme on multiple sites. They mostly care about content, backlinks, and other traditional factors used in ranking.

One exception to this rule is if a theme is found to violate their rules or guidelines then they could penalize you for using that theme. Examples of this would be a theme used to artificially inflate Adsense clicks, squeeze visitors really hard to join your newsletter, or auto-scrape content to name a few.

Changing the name in the css file won't help as Google is pretty sophisticated at looking at a website's footprint, so it would require doing some html and css name changes. Best just to avoid using any theme that can get you in trouble with them.

Using a normal (free or premium) theme is not something you need to worry about in relation to  Google carrying about it.